# Creating a table with three columns and two rows with no border on 2nd column

Tags: html, html-table

I would need to create a table with 3 columns and 2 rows with no border on 2nd column

For example my code is below...

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="125" width="1037">
 <tbody>        
 <tr>
 <td style="width: 254px">Main Title</td>
 <td style="width: 639px">&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="width: 254px">Lots of Contents Column I</td>
 <td style="width: 639px">Lots of Contents Column II</td>
 <td>Lots of Contents Column III</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

By using the below code I am getting borders on the second row..

I don't need borders on the second row.. I can't use merge.. Because I need that structure.

The only thing what I need is that borders should not be displayed in second row.

But the structure should be remain same.

How can I do that using HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using styles applied to the 'table data' tags instead of border=1 (which is deprecated) might solve your problem here. How you wish to organize the application of these styles will vary depending on how much extra information you want to add to the table, etc. Here is a simple example that accomplishes your goal:

For the html, added a class to each tr (please also note cellpadding/cellspacing is also deprecated):

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="125" width="1037">
<tbody>       
<tr class='border-row'>
<td style="width: 254px">Main Title</td>
<td style="width: 639px">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class = 'no-border-row'>
<td style="width: 254px">Lots of Contents Column I</td>
<td style="width: 639px">Lots of Contents Column II</td>
<td>Lots of Contents Column III</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the css:

```
​.border-row td {
    border-style:solid;  
    border-width:1px;
}

.no-border-row td {
    border-style:none; 
}
```

​You don't really need to specify that the second row doesn't have a border, but maybe you might like to apply some different styles to it in the future.

Comment: I have a doubt here..You added class for tr and write for td.. Will that work.. Because in my case it is not working.

Comment: You wanted something that looked like this right? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5PnJ7/) It seems to be working as expected for me?